# Deployment java app offline

Tags: java, mysql, deployment, installation, offline

I've just finished developing a desktop app, for patients data. I'm using eclipse on mac osx, and mysql server for database access.
I need to install this software on a Desktop Pc that has no internet connection, so i have downloaded java 1.7 installer and mysql server.
Up to now, i put mysql server,the java platform and the program together in a usb drive. 
I Installed everything and it works but my question is...

Is there a way to pack everything to make a full installer? 
I've been searching about java web start, but i think it's for deploying apps via browser, anyway jws needs internet connection (I'm not sure about that, just saying)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wrote a guide about a similar configuration...but it's in Italian :( Since there're several code snippet I think you can get some insight from that anyway. Check out this link http://elblog.elbuild.it/2011/02/20/usare-nsis-per-distribuire-applicazioni-javamysql/